# MacVim 8.0 is now available -- you have 8.1.72

Tags: vim

Lately, when I start up MacVim, it pops up a notice that says "MacVim 8.0 is now available--you have 8.1.72.  Would you like to download it now?" .  It sounds like it is asking me to downgrade from 8.1.72 to 8.0 .  What's going on?  I'm ignoring it for now.
[image: Popup window from MacVim]

Comment: Since this is a specific issue with MacVim (very likely a minor bug) and not related to programming in general it is considered off-topic to the scope of StackOverflow. I encourage you sir to post this report at the MacVim [issue tracker](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues) page. In doing so, there will be a better change of getting it fixed too. Thanks!

Comment: After a quick search I found an [open issue](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/694) describing this problem, so I think it's already known. It looks like MacVim is offering you 8.1.280 (judging from the text) but in fact it formats it incorrectly.